# flet build stuck at Extracting Python distributive

Tags: python, flet

So i'm trying to make my app an APK, when I run `flet` build APK (with the terminal opened at the main.py directory).

OK

Packaging Python app...

```
Run subprocess: ['C:\\src\\flutter\\flutter\\bin\\dart.BAT', 'run', 'serious_python:main', 'package', 'C:\\Users\\arell\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\ORACLE ONE\\PROYECTOS\\PROYECTO PYTHON\\PROYECTO MOVIL   
APP', '--mobile', '--platform', 'mobile', '--dep-mappings', 'flet=flet-embed', '--req-deps', 'flet-embed', '--exclude', 'build']
Building package executable... (1.4s)
Built serious_python:main.
Running package command
Creating asset directory: C:\Users\arell\AppData\Local\Temp\flet_flutter_build_hJVrlDvXMI\app
Copying Python app from C:\Users\arell\OneDrive\Escritorio\ORACLE ONE\PROYECTOS\PROYECTO PYTHON\PROYECTO MOVIL APP to C:\Users\arell\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_temp5b5422bc
Configured mobile platform with sitecustomize.py at C:\Users\arell\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_sitecustomize1adfd231\sitecustomize.py
Installing dependencies [pymysql, flet-embed, bcrypt, requests, beautifulsoup4] with pip command to C:\Users\arell\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_temp5b5422bc\__pypackages__
Extracting Python distributive from C:\Users\arell\AppData\Local\Temp\cpython-3.11.6+20231002-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc-shared-install_only.tar.gz to C:\Users\arell\AppData\Local\Temp\hostpython3.11_e97186f9
```

Everything goes well up until we get to that point, it just gets stuck... No code error, nothing, I am forced to kill the terminal and "try again"

I tried using android studio to make the conversión using the `serious_python` templates with no success, this are the `requirements.txt`

```
pymysql
flet
bcrypt
requests
beautifulsoup4
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, so it seems that bcrypt module in 'requirements.txt' "freezes" the extracting.
I tried with hashlib instead and it built correctly